# Writing pre/post-deployment scripts for column add in SSDT on table referenced via foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, data-migration

I'm having an issue writing a reliable data migration using SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).  My schema looks like this:

```
create table [dbo].[Orders]
(
    Id INT identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    OrderDate date NOT NULL,
    constraint PK_dbo_Orders primary key clustered (Id)
)

--has a foreign key to Orders, on delete block
create table [dbo].[OrderItems]
(
    OrderId int not null,
    ItemNumber varchar(20) not null,
    Quantity int not null,
    constraint PK_OrderItems primary key clustered (OrderId, ItemNumber),
    constraint FK_OrderItems_OrderId foreign key (OrderId) references dbo.Orders(Id)
)
```

I want to add a column 'OnlineOrder bit not null' to the Orders table between Id and OrderDate.  Since a simple 'alter table' won't suffice (non-nullable, no default), I have to do the migration manually.  My attempted scripts look like so:

**Predeployment:**

```
--if Orders exists
if exists(select 1 from sys.tables where name = 'Orders')
begin
    --save the data
    select * into _tmp_Orders from Orders
    --empty the existing table
    delete from Orders

    if @@ERROR <> 0
    begin
        drop table _tmp_Orders
    end
end
```

**Postdeployment:**

```
if exists(select 1 from sys.tables where name = 'Orders')
    and exists(select 1 from sys.tables where name = '_tmp_Orders')
begin
    --fill the orders table back up
    insert into Orders(Id, CustomerId, OrderDate, OnlineOrder)
        select Id, CustomerId, OrderDate, 0
        from _tmp_Orders

    if @@ERROR = 0
    begin
        drop table _tmp_Orders
    end
end
```

This would work, but unfortunately the foreign key from OrderItems -> Order blocks the deletion in the pre-deployment script and the whole thing blows up.  I *thought* SSDT disabled constraints *before* pre-deploy and re-enabled them *after* post-deploy, but this apparently only applies to triggers, not constraints/foreign keys.

**Question #1:** Is there a way to force SSDT to disable all FKs in the database (including those 'unknown' to my .dacpac) for the duration of the deployment?  This would be the easiest.

**Question #2:** If not, I'll have to NOCHECK these constraints myself.  Is there a reason SSDT doesn't do this by default (aka, a reason I also shouldn't do this?)

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You may have stumbled on one of the few cases when the "smart defaults" feature is of use.

Given that you are adding a `bit` column, and pre-populating with zeros, if you check "Generate smart defaults, when applicable" in your publish profile (or supply the corresponding parameter to `sqlpackage.exe`) you will get the column pre-populated with zeros. This feature works by creating a default and then dropping it as soon as the column is created.

Does this help at all?

Comment: That does work for this case, but I'm looking to extrapolate to a solution to a more general problem.  I want a pattern to be able to save data into a temp table for an arbitrary table (useful for table splits, etc).  Foreign keys are getting in the way

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in some case it is impossible to use only pre- and post-deployment scripts to complete the task.

Suppose you need to:

- add a lookup table,
- add a column to the existing table which is full of data, and where that column has to be `not null` foreign key to the lookup table.

I doubt this task can be accomplished with pre- and post-deployment scripts, even with the smart defaults.

*The lookup table is filled in post-deployment script, so the foreign
key is  created before the lookup table is populated - here is the
error.*

Added by [user1935361](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1935361/user1935361):

> The above quote is inaccurate.
>
> The foreign key is
>   created, but it's created WITH NOCHECK. The post-deployment script
>   runs after the foreign key is created, but before it's actually
>   checked (just verified this).

The other problem is that pre-deployment executes after the schema comparison! So the publication catches the error in schema and throws it before the pre-deployment script execution. See [the article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gertd/2009/09/14/pre-deployment-scripts/) of Gert Drapers about that. I have not heard that this behavior has changed since 2009.

So the workaround is to create *before-deployment* script (or how Gert Drapers calls it *pre-pre-deployment*) and execute it before the common publishing process.

If to do that outside Visual Studio then it can be an execution of PowerShell script:

- first - run *before-deployment* script,
- second - run SqlPackage.exe with compiled *.dacpac.

If you need to automate the process in Visual Studio... it is a challenge. There is no 'BeforePublish' MsBuild Task (correct me if I am wrong). So we cannot execute *before-deployment* script before a database publication when right-click on *.publish.xml profile and choose "Publish..."

But we can catch `AfterBuild` task and execute PowerShell script which does those two steps above.

```html
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    ... Run PowerShell script here
</Target>
```

Thereby database publication will perform every time when database is built, but for sure with *before-deployment* script. If it is annoying, switch off the database from the solution build in Configuration Manager and build the database project separatelly.

Comment: Can you edit this answer to include the following? The following quote is inaccurate:  "_The lookup table is filled in post-deployment script, so the foreign key is created before the lookup table is populated - here is the error._".  The foreign key is created, but it's created WITH NOCHECK.  The post-deployment script runs after the foreign key is created, but before it's actually checked (just verified this).

Comment: A more popular form of dropping a table is to check if it exists and then drop it like so: if object_id('dbo.test','U') is not null drop table dbo.test You may also want to start using begin try for checking for errors.